# Load javascript when page load in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I try this method , but it is not working for me , I am beginner in AngulartJS

```js
var getDb = angular.module('dataapp', [])
  .controller('datagetcontroller', function ($scope,$window) {
    $window.onload = function(){
      alert('this is test')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<tr ng-app="dataapp" ng-controller="datagetcontroller"><td>loremipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr>
```

Thank in advance.

--UPDATE--
Maybe I have problem , because before new page load I use page redirect via

> window.location.href

, which help I redirect to page where I need to  execute javascript.

Comment: I have the same problem , that is why I ask experts to help me. I need for example when page load finish . Alert me something

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43877226/6712896) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13059284/6712896) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/how-to-execute-angular-controller-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 2):

```
    var getDb = angular.module('dataapp', [])
    .controller('datagetcontroller', function ($scope) {
    //assign to scope function
    $scope.load = function() {
           alert("Window is loaded");
     }}});



 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
//call load function in ng-init
<tr ng-app="dataapp" ng-controller="datagetcontroller" ng-init="load()"><td>loremipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr>
```

Comment: Sorry , but it did not help , please  if you can look I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I have also added a working plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/DD0BeZLqZbZcoxCDNi1g?p=preview.
>   Suppose your .js file is script.js which looks like:
>
> `var getDb = angular.module('dataapp', [])
>
>   .controller('datagetcontroller', function ($scope,$window) {
>       $window.onload = function(){
>         alert('this is test')
>       } });`
>
> > and your html page is index.html where head should look like have:
> >          
> >         `<head>
> >         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
> >         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
> >         <script src="script.js"></script> 
> >        </head> 
> >        <body ng-app="dataapp"> 
> >        <table>
> >            <tr ng-controller="datagetcontroller">
> >               <td>loremipsum</td>
> >               <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
> >            </tr>
> >        </table>
> >     </body>`
>
> It should work fine. I think you have not declared the **script.js**
>   file in the index.html where you have written the javascript. Also
>   note that, you have to place the **angular.min.js** script above the
>   **script.js** as angular needs to load before hand so that script.js understands the code.

Comment: Your noted solution has not helped . But Thank.

Comment: are you facing any error in the console? did you check the plunkr link I have attached?

Comment: Yes I have check your attached solution , but it does not execute javascript in my situation. But in plunker it works perfect. I have just update my answer , maybe my problem is my updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution

```js
angular.element(window).bind('load', function() {
    
});
```

Other reason that my angular did not work , was in a simple mistake , I do not have right to use more than one ng-app="" inside one html file